# Div set to 100% width and 100% height, but not inheriting size of parent div

Tags: jquery, html, css, width

I have a parent div with div inside it that I want to set to the same size as the parent div. The parent div is set to inline-block. How can I do this? https://jsfiddle.net/7twc7jy0/

```
<div class= "parent">
   <div class="caption">
      <h4>Thumbnail Headline</h4>
      <p>short thumbnail description</p>
   </div>
   <img class="project-img" src="https://i.imgur.com/UnxgcnT.png" >
</div>
```

css:

```
.project-img{
  width:400px;
  height: auto;
}

.parent{
  display:inline-block;
}

.caption {
    position:absolute;
    background:rgba(66, 139, 202, 0.75);
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    padding:0%;
    margin:0%;
    display: none;
    text-align:center;
    color:#fff !important;
    z-index:2;
}
```

JS:

```
$('.parent').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(150)
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(150); //.fadeOut(205)
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You Must add position relative on your parent div

```
.proj{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
}
```

This should do the Job

Answer (score -1):

you should set parent like this:

```
.parent {
    padding:0%
}
```